# getting error "results in empty target node" while selecting multiple nodes

Tags: xpath, jaxb2

I have an WSDL like below

```
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://pk/training/basit/webservice/message/lmsapi/serviceoperations">
<wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://pk/training/basit/webservice/message/lmsapi/serviceoperations">
        <xsd:import namespace="http://trainingplan.types.lmsapi.message.webservice.basit.training.pk"/>
        ...
        <xsd:element name="CreateTrainingPlanRequest">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="TrainingPlans" type="ns0:TrainingPlans"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:attribute name="customerCode" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
                <xsd:attribute name="key" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="CreateTrainingPlanResponse">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="ResponseTrainingPlans" type="ns0:ResponseTrainingPlans"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:attribute name="transactionResult" type="TransactionResultType" use="required"/>
                <xsd:attribute name="transactionResultMessage" type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="AssignTrainingPlanToLearnerRequest">
            ...
        </xsd:element>
        ....
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Now i want to select all three elements with name attributes using XPath. When i did the following i get the value

```
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="http://localhost:8080/lms/service/lms-api/lmsApi.wsdl" node="/wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xsd:schema[@targetNamespace='http://pk/training/basit/webservice/message/lmsapi/serviceoperations']/xsd:element[@name='CreateTrainingPlanRequest']">
```

but when i try to select multiple nodes, like

```
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="http://localhost:8080/lms/service/lms-api/lmsApi.wsdl" node="/wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xsd:schema[@targetNamespace='http://pk/training/basit/webservice/message/lmsapi/serviceoperations']/xsd:element[@name='CreateTrainingPlanRequest' and @name='CreateTrainingPlanResponse' and @name='AssignTrainingPlanToLearnerRequest']">
```

then i get the following error

```
com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2: XPath evaluation of "/wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xsd:schema[@targetNamespace='http:/pk/training/basit/webservice/message/lmsapi/serviceoperations']/xsd:element[@name='CreateTrainingPlanRequest' and @name='CreateTrainingPlanResponse' and @name='AssignTrainingPlanToLearnerRequest']" results in empty target node
```

why i am getting empty nodes. What is wrong with my XPath expression ?

Thanks

**Edit :
--------------------------------**

```
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="http://localhost:8080/lms/service/lms-api/lmsApi.wsdl" node="/wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xsd:schema[@targetNamespace='http://pk/training/basit/webservice/message/lmsapi/serviceoperations']/xsd:element[@name='CreateTrainingPlanRequest' or @name='CreateTrainingPlanResponse' or @name='AssignTrainingPlanToLearnerRequest']">
    <jaxb:schemaBindings>
        <jaxb:package name="pk.training.basit.webservice.messages.lmsapi.serviceoperations.trainingplan" />
    </jaxb:schemaBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>

<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="http://localhost:8080/lms/service/lms-api/lmsApi.wsdl" node="/wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xsd:schema[@targetNamespace='http://pk/training/basit/webservice/message/lmsapi/serviceoperations'](/xsd:element[@name='AddCustomerRequest']) and (/xsd:element[@name='AddCustomerResponse'])">
    <jaxb:schemaBindings>
        <jaxb:package name="pk.training.basit.webservice.messages.lmsapi.serviceoperations.customer" />
    </jaxb:schemaBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you say

```
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="http://localhost:8080/lms/service/lms-api/lmsApi.wsdl"
 node="/wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xsd:schema[
  @targetNamespace='http://pk/training/basit/webservice/message/lmsapi/serviceoperations'
]/xsd:element[@name='CreateTrainingPlanRequest' and @name='CreateTrainingPlanResponse'
   and @name='AssignTrainingPlanToLearnerRequest']">
```

you are asking for any `xsd:element` for which the `@name` attribute has three different values, on the same element. That's not possible. Maybe instead you want

```
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="http://localhost:8080/lms/service/lms-api/lmsApi.wsdl"
 node="/wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xsd:schema[
  @targetNamespace='http://pk/training/basit/webservice/message/lmsapi/serviceoperations'
]/xsd:element[@name='CreateTrainingPlanRequest' or @name='CreateTrainingPlanResponse'
   or @name='AssignTrainingPlanToLearnerRequest']">
```

i.e. change `and` to `or`.

## Update:

If you're trying to select an `xsd:schema` element that has `xsd:element` children with all three names, here is the XPath expression you need:

```
node="/wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xsd:schema[
  @targetNamespace='http://pk/training/basit/webservice/message/lmsapi/serviceoperations'
 and xsd:element[@name='CreateTrainingPlanRequest'] and 
  xsd:element[@name='CreateTrainingPlanResponse'] and
  xsd:element[@name='AssignTrainingPlanToLearnerRequest']"
```

Comment: Hmm thanks, i did what you said, i mean change `and` to `or` but now i am getting the error `results in too many (3) target nodes`. May be i missed something to tell that why i want to do it. Actually i want to select these three nodes and put them in a single package. Wait i edit my post to show full jaxb binding code

Comment: @Basit, what is it you are trying to select? an `xsd:schema` element?

Comment: If you have further changes to the question, you may need to ask a new question.

Comment: I want to select all three elements `CreateTrainingPlanRequest`, `CreateTrainingPlanResponse` and `AssignTrainingPlanToLearnerRequest` which come under schema element having targetnamespace that i provided. I am generating java classes from this WSDL. So i want that these three elments are selected , classes generate from these elements and then these classes come under package `pk.training.basit.webservice.messages.lmsapi.serviceoperations.trainingplan`

Comment: Thanks, tried, but now getting error that `Can not convert #BOOLEAN to a NodeList!`

Comment: @Basit: I don't see how that error can be produced by that XPath expression. Maybe you'll need someone else to help you.